# Is there a "contains" method for the Tkinter Listbox widget

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Is there a `listbox.contains()` for python Tkinter similiar to the C# method?

I know the answer is probably NO but I need to check if the first 6 chars in a listbox item exist,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. However, all the basic functionality is there for you to write your own. It would look something like this:

```
class CustomListbox(tk.Listbox):
    def __contains__(self, str):
        return str in self.get(0, "end")

lb = CustomListbox(...)
...
lb.insert("end", "foo")
...
if "foo" in lb:
    print "success"
```

Or, using a lambda to attach the function to a standard listbox:

```
lb = tk.Listbox(...)
lb.__contains__ = lambda str: str in lb.get(0, "end")
...
lb.insert("end", "foo")
...
if "foo" in lb:
    print "success"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a method like that:

```
def contain(item):
    iscontain= item in listbox.get(0, "end")
    return iscontain
```